# Bucketby Property with Spark saveastable method taking spark 'default' database instead of hive database: HDP 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdp

I'm saving Spark DataFrame using saveAsTable method and  writing below code.

```
    val options = Map("path" -> hiveTablePath)
    df.write.format("orc")
    .partitionBy("partitioncolumn")
    .options(options)
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .saveAsTable(hiveTable)
```

It's working fine and i am able to see data in hive table. but when I'm using one more property bucketby(5,bucketted_column)

```
    df.write.format("orc")
    .partitionBy("partitioncolumn")
    .bucketby(5,bucketted_column)
    .options(options)
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .saveAsTable(hiveTable)
```

It's trying to save it in spark 'default' database instead of hive database.

can someone please suggest me why bucketby(5,bucketted_column) is not working with saveAsTable.

```
    Note: Framework: HDP 3.0
    Spark : 2.1
```

Comment: defaut is also Hive if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this parameter:

```
.option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.write.mode...saveAsTable("database.table")` should do the trick.

Except that the bucketBy format cannot be read via Hive, Hue, Impala. Currently not supported.

> > > Not sure what you mean by spark db, I think you mean Spark metastore?

Comment: tried this but in this case showing database not found.

Comment: the name of the database substituted I assume. The database must exist of course, or your process has access to it.

Comment: Yes the database exists and I'm accessing the same database's table while selecting data in df. i.e. val df=spark.sql("select * from mydb.mytable") and saving this dataframe in same database in next step   my target table "hiveTable" is also available in same database.i.e.mydb with same structure I'm able to save partitioned data as well in table but whenever i'm using bucketby instead of taking 'mydb' its taking spark database i.e. 'default'.@thebluephantom

Comment: Updating answer.